# Is taskkill safe to close a process?

Tags: batch-file, taskkill

I want to be able to close a process on a remote computer using a .bat file.
eg: taskkill /im Myapp.exe

Is using taskkill a suitable way to close an application?  eg like clicking the 'X' on the toolbar?

Does it give the app time to run all of it's closing down methods/destructors?  Or does it cause it to end abruptly, losing any data that hasn't had a chance to be written before closing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you dont use /f.

Comment: According to the documentation http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx it actually will always forcefully terminate a remote process.  The /f switch is only for local processes.